# Example of using AdditionalMetadata in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

In asp.net MVC 3 there is a new attribute that allows us to pass additional Meta Data to our views e.g.

```
    [Required]
    [AdditionalMetadata("Tooltip", "The title of the item")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

The question is, how do I actually make use of this information in my view? I thought that perhaps it would render out the data as html 5 data attributes but this is not the case.

A simple example would be much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, you're responsible for rummaging through [ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.additionalvalues.aspx) within your templates to make use of this.  Dunno if there are any "default" keys that come in useful out of the box.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#_Toc2_2):

> You can use the
>   AdditionalMetadataAttribute class to
>   populate the
>   ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues
>   dictionary for a model property.
>
> ...
>
> This metadata is made available to any
>   display or editor template when a
>   product view model is rendered. It is
>   up to you as application developer to
>   interpret the metadata information.

So let's make use of it in the view:

```
<h2>
    @ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.Title, ViewData).AdditionalValues["Tooltip"]
</h2>
```

Comment: Would you also show us it working in an Editor Template? - ta

Comment: me again, sorry, ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["Tooltip"]

Answer (score 0):

example in a template:

```
Object optionlabelOverride;
ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.TryGetValue("OptionLabelText", out optionLabelOverride);
```

the variable you are reading must be an object and then you can cast it.  Everything you set in the model is available as ViewData.